# Importing a js file outside the src directory in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a js file which contains some data, in the public directory. And I want to change them even after the building. And I don't like to build every time I change that file. How can I import that data.js file without getting "Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported." error.
The project was created using create-react-app.

Comment: what type of data we are talking here.

Comment: JS file with a object containing data

Comment: Like const data = { [{x:y, x1:y1...}],... }

Answer (score 0):

You need to include it using a script tag in the index.html file in your public folder.

Comment: But how can I import it to the react files?

Comment: You should be able to access the global variables from within React, at most you would just have to use the window object. i.e. `window.var1`